# An array has 2 elements. One element is unique and the other can repeat any number of times. Find the distinct element in < O(n) time

Tags: arrays

O(n) solution is straight forward. I can think of something in terms of binary search but that again will be O(n) in worst case as the input array need not be sorted. Is there any solution that runs in O(log n) time?

Answer (score 0):

May be one of the solution can be based on divide and conquer techniques.

eg Array -> [2,2,2,2,3,2,2]

```
Take three variables `First`, `Mid` and `Last`
1. Find `First` first element     -> 2 in our case.
2. Find length of array   -> 7 
3. Find `Mid` element     -> 4
4. Sum till `Mid` element   -> 2+2+2+2=8 (calculate by Mid * First)
5. If sum from `First` and `Mid` is equal to (`Mid` * `First`) then set `First` as `Mid`+-1 else set `Last` as `Mid`+1
```

The above method will divide the array to half for each comparision in worst case scenario.

Comment: But it isn't guaranteed to see < O(n) elements. The worst case happens when the unique element occurs in the last, in which case, for the step 4 (sum till `Mid` element) will traverse all the elements of the array thereby making it O(n)? Am I right?

Comment: for worst cases, otherwise it has complexity of order `O(log n)` , suppose you have just 3 elements [2,2,3]/[2,3,2]/[3,2,2] in this case using this you will get element in 2, 1 and 2 checks respectively and its less than O(n). May be there are better solutions, but this is definitly better than O(n)